# Zabbix (5.0) Discovery Rule not working

Tags: zabbix

The background.
I have an application that I want to monitor using a REST API. To get the information I need requires two calls to the REST API.

The first one is like:

```
`http://{IPADDRESS}:1234/api/20190715/metadata`
```

This returns:

```
`{"items":[{"name":"the_test_name"}]}`
```

From which I extract `the_test_name` using the JSONPath PreProcessing.

The second call is then:

```
`http://{IPADDRESS}:1234/api/20190715/metadata/the_test_name/status
```

As you can see I need to pass the result of the first one into the second one. My understanding is that this can't easily be done as two separate `items`, but it may be possible to with `discovery Processes`.

So far I have a template and two hosts. The template has three standard `items` on, all of which are working fine on the hosts. And are basically the same REST API calls above but with the value HardCoded in the string.

To the template I have then added a `Discovery Rule` which is basically the first API call above (and basically the same as the standard `items`).
It has a PreProcessing value of:

```
`JSONPath : $.items[0].name`
```

and an LLD Macro set up as:

```
`{#CL_NAME} : $.items[0].name`
```

If I click the `TEST` button, and add the IP Address of the server I get the correct result, e.g. `the_test_name`.

I then have an `item_prototype` set up as:

```
`http://{IPADDRESS}:1234/api/20190715/metadata/{#CL_NAME}/status`
```

and a PreProcessing Value of:

```
`JSONPATH: $.timeLastRefreshSucceeded`
```

If I `TEST` this, and put in the `IPAddress` and the `{#CL_NAME}` values, it works fine.

However, I then go to my `host` > click on `Discovery` > `item_Prototypes` > the itemName > `PreProcessing` > `Test`.

I tick `Get Value From Host`, fill in the two Macros, and it works fine.

But back on the `host` > `Discovery`, the `info` box is red and says:

```
`Invalid Discovery Rule: cannot Parse as Valid JSON object. Invalid Object Format. Expected Opening Character '{' or '[' at 'the_test_name'`
```

I've tried adding and removing steps from eveywhere, but it still just says it's invalid. What am I Missing!!!!

Answer (score 0):

OK so the zabbix docs may not be perfectly clear as how to construct a LLD low level discovery item prototypes but in short - zabbix expects a JSON return from your LLD item - something like this:

```
# mkdir /tmp/test_files/
# touch /tmp/test_files/a
# touch /tmp/test_files/b
# touch /tmp/test_files/c
# ./userparameter_file_discovery.sh /tmp/test_files/
{
  "data":[
  {
     "{#FILE}": "/tmp/test_files/b"
  },
  {
     "{#FILE}": "/tmp/test_files/c"
  },
  {
     "{#FILE}": "/tmp/test_files/a"
  }
  ]
}
```

for me :) the saying - if you have a hammer in your hand - everything becomes a nail is unfortunately true so I know how to code in bash and use & miss-use zabbix user parameters so I'll give you contents of script used to generate that output here - you can adjust the input to your API calls with `curl` I guess:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Distribute with zabbix_agent.d file userparameter_file_discovery.conf
# 1st mandatory argument is absolute path of destination directory
# 2nd optional argument is maxdepth number for find
# 3rd optional argument is filemask for grep
#
# TODO: adjust for files with white space chars
# Author:       Roman Spiak
# Email:        spiak.roman@gmail.com
# Mod.Date:     2020-06-04

argCount=$#

# argument count check
if [ $argCount -lt 1 ] || [ $argCount -gt 3 ]; then
        echo ERROR: argument count missmatch
        exit 1
fi

dir=$1
if [ $argCount -eq 1 ]; then
        maxDepth=1
        fileMask="."
elif [ $argCount -eq 2 ]; then
        maxDepth=$2
        fileMask="."
else
        maxDepth=$2
        fileMask=$3
fi

filePaths=`find $dir -maxdepth $maxDepth -type f|grep $fileMask`
fileCount=`echo $filePaths|wc -w`

iter=0

echo '{'
echo '  "data":['
for i in $filePaths; do
        echo '  {'
        echo "     \"{#FILE}\": \"$i\""
        iter=$((iter+1))
        if [ $iter -eq $fileCount ]; then
                echo '  }'
        else
                echo '  },'
        fi
done
echo '  ]'
echo '}'
```

and the userparm conf file:

```
# UserParameter to autodiscover files inside a provided directory
# Distribute with bash script userparameter_file_discovery.sh
# 1st argument is absolute path of destination directory
# 2nd argument is maxdepth number for find
# 3rd argument is filemask for grep
#
# Author:   Roman Spiak
# Email:    roman.spiak@zsdis.sk
# Mod.Date: 2020-06-02

UserParameter=file.discovery[*],/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.d/userparameter_file_discovery.sh $1 $2 $3
```

Answer (score 0):

reading my previous answer - the whole LLD in your case is a big overkill so let's try some simple bash script that should be enough for your use-case:

```
#!/bin/bash
# this script uses jq - details on http://www.compciv.org/recipes/cli/jq-for-parsing-json/
# Let's assume IPADDR is passed via $1 to this bash - in zabbix via arg [*]

IPADDRESS=$1

NAME=`curl http://$IPADDRESS:1234/api/20190715/metadata|jq '.items[]'|jq '.name'`

STATUS=`curl http://$IPADDRESS:1234/api/20190715/metadata/$NAME/status`

echo $STATUS
```

Comment: to test the jq I did the following: 

`# cat js
{
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "the_test_name"
    }
  ]
}
# cat js|jq '.items[]'|jq '.name'
"the_test_name"`